# urls with object

Tags: django

I have element in my urls.py

```
url(r'^name/(?P<some_id>.+)/$', Class(), name='name'),
```

Is it possible somehow to receive some_id in class?

Comment: Be careful: this is not thread-safe. The same instance of `Class` will be used for every call within this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a class instance as view, its `__call__` method will be executed. The parameters passed are the same as in function-based views (except the `self` as first argument). Text that you capture in your regex will be passed as string to the function/method. ([Capturing text in urls](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#notes-on-capturing-text-in-urls))

```
class A(object):

    def __call__(self, request, some_id):
        # stuff
```

If you don't already know this, Django will use class-based views (besides the function-based) as of version 1.3. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with decorator.

```
def accepts_some_object(f):
    def new_f(request, some_object_id, *args, **kwargs):
        some_object = get_object_or_404(...)
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs, some_object=some_object)
    return new_f

@accepts_some_object
def some_view(request, some_object)
```

Useful if you have many views which accept `some_object`.